# Why I don't see a new app "DevHub" after enabling DevHub?

Tags: salesforcedx

We have enabled DevHub in our production org and now we are struggling to find all data/objects etc. related to the DevHub. When I tried DX in a [trial org](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/dx-signup) that has Dev Hub enabled, there was an application "DevHub" which comprised all related object.

So why Salesforce didn't create a new app this time, and do I need to do it on my own?

Comment: Are you using the classic interface, or lightning experience? Dunno if I've ever seen an "app" for it. I've always just gone to the setup menu and typed "dev hub" in the quick search box.

Comment: We are using Lightning. Ya, I can find DevHub using the Quick Search in Setup. What I am asking for is how I can see all related tabs, Active Scratch Orgs for instance. Right now I have to use the App Launcher and look up this tabs. Moreover, I have to guess what other tabs relate to DevHub, like Scratch Org Infos etc. If there was an app for this which I could switch to and see all these, like in the Trial Org, it would be more logical. So there should be a reason why Salesforce haven't provided such an app. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a tab for DevHub in our org, just the sliders in setup to turn on the DevHub. If you aren't using the salesforcedx CLI tool, check it out, you can easily see your scratch orgs and DevHub from the CLI tool.

[SFDX CLI tool Installer](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)

The command is

```
sfdx force:org:list --all
```